# Python error with Pyx module: 'SingleLatexRunner' object has no attribute 'texoutput'

Tags: python, tex, pyx

In Windows command prompt, I get error message

```
 AttributeError: 'SingleLatexRunner' object has no attribute 'texoutput'
```

when running Pyx module in python to make plot as pdf file.

A pdf file is made but nothing is inside it (0 KB)

The code works on another computer but I get this error message on new computer

What is cause of such error and how to solve?

Thank you.

Comment: At first glance I would assume that `texoutput` should be `textoutput`. However, without seeing the code it's hard to tell. I can't imagine `texoutput` is correct.

Comment: Hi @Kevin "texoutput" does not appear in the python code. I think "tex" refers to LaTex I am using. The code works on another computer but I get this error message on new computer

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is if you are running the same version of python on the new computer. Sometimes that can cause problems like this. Check `python --version` on both computers.

Comment: Could you add a call `pyxinfo()` immediately after the PyX import statement? Keep the rest of your code running after calling this. The generated output would be rather interesting ...

Comment: @Kevin Welch Thanks it was wrong python version